# Differential equation$y'=\frac{3}{x}y+2$ with condition $y(1)=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find solution of this differential equation?

$$y'=\frac{3}{x}y+2$$ with condition $y(1)=2$.

I found in homogenous case that $y(x)=x^3$ but I couldn't find the non-homogenous case.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Hint: integrating factor.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: "I found in homogenous case that $y(x)=x^3$ but I couldn't find the non-homogenous case." And yet, the standard procedure works... First, the solutions of the homogenous case are $$y(x)=cx^3,$$ not only $y(x)=x^3$, next, the method recommends the change of variable $$y(x)=z(x)x^3,$$ that is, an unknown function time a homogenous solution, which yields  $$y'(x)=z'(x)x^3+3z(x)x^2=z'(x)x^3+3y(x)/x,$$ hence $y$ is a solution if and only if $$z'(x)x^3=2,$$ that is, $$z'(x)=2/x^3=(-1/x^2)',$$ that is, $$z(x)=c-1/x^2,$$ that is finally, $$y(x)=cx^3-x,$$ and if $y(1)=2$, $$y(x)=3x^3-x.$$

Answer (score 3):

By writing as
$$y'-\frac{3}{x}y=2,\qquad y(1)=2\tag{1}$$
Now, note that $$\mu(x)=e^{\int-\frac{3}{x}dx}=e^{-3\ln x}=x^{-3}$$
is an integrating factor of $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

#### Hint:

multiply by $x$ to become the [Euler-Cauchy equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)
$$xy'-3y=2x$$
the complementary solution from
$$xy'-3y=0$$

the particular solution
$$y_p=Ax$$

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. [Integrating factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html)
2. [Leibniz' method](http://livetoad.org/Courses/Documents/214a/Notes/first-order_linear.pdf) (I think they are the same though):

A linear ODE

$$y' = p(x) y + g(x)$$

for well-behaved functions $p$ and $g$ has solution

$$y = \exp\{-\int p(x) dx\} \int [g(x)\exp\{\int p(x) dx\} + A] dx$$