# Streamline of $[x, 2x+3y]$ at $(4,5)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

My book doesn't explain this thoroughly, but apparently I'm supposed to start by solving

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac{2x+3y}{x}$$

But is the rest correct?

$$\mathrm{d}y = \dfrac{2x+3y}{x}\mathrm{d}x \implies y = 2x+3y\ln x+C \implies y = \dfrac{2x+C}{1-3\ln x}$$

at $(4,5)$:

$$5 = \dfrac{2(4)+C'}{1+3\ln (4)} \implies C' = \dfrac{5+30\ln 2}{8} \implies y = \dfrac{2x+C'}{1-3\ln x}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differential equation$y'=\frac{3}{x}y+2$ with condition $y(1)=2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657937/differential-equationy-frac3xy2-with-condition-y1-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

This does not seem to be correct.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{2x+3y}{x}\implies \frac{dy}{dx}-3\frac{y}x =2$$ Solve the homegeneous equation first (it is quite simple). Then, use the variation of parameters to take into account the rhs.

I am sure that you can take it from here.